# Decompose array to function arguments in TypeScript\JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of object instances with different types.

```
var instances: any = [];
instances["Object1"] = new TypeA();
instances["ObjectB"] = new TypeB();
```

Each type have own methods with different names and number of arguments.
I want to call this methods by calling one function and passing to it data to identify the method to call and necessary argument values(I send this data from client).

```
function CallMethod(data){
  let args = data.args;// it's array
  instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](??????); 
}
```

Is it possible to automatic decompose `args` array to pass his values as different function arguments?

Like this:

```
instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](args[0], args[1], ... args[n]);
```

Comment: Either use the spread operator, either use `.call` or `.apply` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: I wanted to provide a type safe version of this ... but I guess since it got quickly closed I can't anymore :(

Comment: `class TypeA { method(s: string) { } }
class TypeB { foo(s: string, n: number) { } bar(n: number) { } }
var instances = { "Object1": new TypeA(), "ObjectB": new TypeB(), }
function CallMethod<
    K extends keyof typeof instances,
    M extends keyof typeof instances[K]>(data: { objectId: K } & { methodId: M } & {
        args: typeof instances[K][M] extends (...a: any) => any ? Parameters<typeof instances[K][M]> : never
    }) { let args = data.args; (instances[data.objectId][data.methodId] as any)(...args); }`

Comment: Sounds great, but can you explain your solution? Especially this line: ```{ args: typeof instances[K][M] extends (...a: any) => any ? Parameters<typeof instances[K][M]> : never }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [**Spread Syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_function_calls)

```
function CallMethod(data){
  let args = data.args;// it's array
  instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](...args); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can destruct the array for function parameters using `...` It is also known as spread. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

```
instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](...args);
```

so your function will be:

```
function CallMethod(data){
    let args = data.args;// it's array
    instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](...args); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

spread operator will work here

```
function CallMethod(data){
  let args = data.args;
  instances[data.objectId][data.methodId](...args); 
}
```